# PHP REGEX and segmenting a String

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

So what I am trying to do is have this `$d` array (in reality I will be extracting value from a excel cell). But I created a array for the example. Each set of string in the array notice has a ';' somewhere, and some strings have 'AKA' and some have 'UNKNOWN'  The strings are random, so I am not sure which one will show up in excel cell. What I need is trying to extract the first name and last name before the first 'AKA'. Also trying to extract the first name last name in front of the first ';'. And identify the 'UNKNOWN' String.

I apply a preg match with $r first to identify by ';'.
Next I identify if 'AKA' exists in $re22.
Now where I am stuck is: I know that 'AKA' does exist in 2 of the array strings. Now I want to apply $r23 on those 2 array strings that have 'AKA'...After I want to store them ? How do i do this??

```
$r = "/(^.*?)(?=;|$)/";
$re22 = "/(AKA)/";
$re24 = "/(UNKNOWN)/";
$r23 = "/(^.*?)(?=AKA|$)/";

$d = ["AMALIAOKLP RETTOMATTIS AKA AMALIAOKLP M RETTOMATTIS; ROSCAR RETTOMATTIS AKA ROSCAR ALBERTO RETTOMATTIS AKA ROSCAR A RETTOMATTIS",
 "IVESS PALM IMPROVEMENT INC; HHJP KGSEING LAANK ASSOCIATION; REWQROYAL MYLLWORK INC; REWAABCO TOOFING INC; UNITED",
"DAVID  SWEREISENSON; RONA  SWEREISENSON; MELLINGTON; TEEGATTA BAY; LATIONAL CITY", "JAMES DECIMA AKA JAMES P DECIMA; GLORIA `enter code here` DECIMA; REARLWOOD ASSOCIATION INC; INC; BORE NA",
"UNKNOWN PARTIES","NATIONAL ASSOCIATION; SAVALENCIA AT INC; ASSEMBLY INC"];

    foreach($d as $x => $x_value) {
  // echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "BREAK. <br>";
   $q = preg_match($r, $x_value, $matches);
    //echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $matches;
var_dump($matches[0]);
 echo "BREAK2. <br>";
 //does 'aka' exist in the matches? if so do next
 $q22 = preg_match($re22, $matches[0], $matches22);
    //echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $matches;
    var_dump($matches22[0]);
 echo "BREAK3.<br>";
 if (in_array('AKA', $matches22, true)) {
    $q25 = preg_match($re23, $matches[0], $matches25);
    var_dump($matches25);
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$matches25` try making it a dynamic array `$matches25[]`. Also your `preg_match` there has a typo, should be `$r23`; `preg_match($re23`

Comment: Couldn't you just use two explode statements, one exploding at the ";" and the other at the "AKA", then you'd have your names all separated

Comment: Are `AMALIAOKLP RETTOMATTIS` and `JAMES DECIMA` the only two names you expect to come out of this? Yea, I was thinking explode on the `;` would be better as well. The `AKA` I think can also be `unknown` so a regex might also be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this approach. Explode on the semi-colons then use a regex on the zero index because you said you only care about the first group in the list.

```
    <?php
$d = array("AMALIAOKLP RETTOMATTIS AKA AMALIAOKLP M RETTOMATTIS; ROSCAR RETTOMATTIS AKA ROSCAR ALBERTO RETTOMATTIS AKA ROSCAR A RETTOMATTIS",
 "IVESS PALM IMPROVEMENT INC; HHJP KGSEING LAANK ASSOCIATION; REWQROYAL MYLLWORK INC; REWAABCO TOOFING INC; UNITED",
"DAVID  SWEREISENSON; RONA  SWEREISENSON; MELLINGTON; TEEGATTA BAY; LATIONAL CITY", "JAMES DECIMA AKA JAMES P DECIMA; GLORIA `enter code here` DECIMA; REARLWOOD ASSOCIATION INC; INC; BORE NA",
"UNKNOWN PARTIES","NATIONAL ASSOCIATION; SAVALENCIA AT INC; ASSEMBLY INC");
foreach($d as $x => $x_value) {
    $split = explode(';', $x_value);
    if(preg_match('~(.*?)\s+(?:AKA|UNKNOWN)~', $split[0], $named)) {
        $store[] = trim($named[1]);
    }
}
print_r($store);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AMALIAOKLP RETTOMATTIS
    [1] => JAMES DECIMA
)
```

... or maybe `unknown` should not be in the same group?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regexes. You can do almost anything with regexes if you set your mind to it. “Can”, not “should”. In this case, for code readability, I think you'd be much better off with a few well-placed calls to [`explode`](http://prototype.php.net/explode). Something like this, perhaps:

```
foreach ($d as $contacts)
{
    /* Split based on semicolons. */
    $contacts = explode('; ', $contacts);
    $primary_contact = $contacts[0];

    $contact_aliases = explode(' AKA ', $contacts[0]);

    if (strpos($contact_aliases[0], 'UNKNOWN') !== FALSE)
        printf("No name found.\n");
    else
        printf("Name: %s\n", $contact_aliases[0]);
}
```

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I was going to actually use the regex features of `split` but then decided against it, and forgot to use `explode` in its place.